# HL Fabric - states, transactions but varied keys

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Edit: Bump -- anyone know the answer to this???

**Basic question:** - in a single HLF application, can different transactions have different keys?

**Context:** Developing a 1.4.2 HLF application that mirrors the fabric samples commercial paper example but which has varied keys for transactions. For example, in commercial paper, the `key` for a PaperNet commercial paper is formed by concatenating the `Issuer` and `paper` properties, e.g. `MagnetoCorp0001`. While `Issuer` and `paper` may change `paper` is always married with `Issuer`. This is consistent throughout the entire commercial paper example.

In our example however, different transactions will have different keys depending on the state. For example, PartyA enters into a contract with BigBiz to be able to license widgets for a fee. We consider this a `contracting transaction` and when completed its state is `underContract` the `key` for it is a concatenation of `licensor` + `licensee` + `contractNumber` or in this example: `BigBizPartyA123`.

Moving through our lifecycle, a contract needs to be in place before BigBiz is going to make a widget available for licensing. The `available` state key for a `available widget transaction` is `licensor` + `widgetID` or in this case `BigBiz0001`.

In our `licensing transaction` the key for our `licensed` state is `licensor` + `widgetID` + `licensee` or `BigBiz0001PartyA`.

**Question** - is this realistic and is this doable?

Unlike commercial paper where `paperNum` always exists, our app from a lifecycle POV won't have a widgetID unless the `contracting transaction` achieves `underContract` state. So there is no widgetID we can key on. Similarly, we have other transactions, like payment transactions, that have nothing to do with widgets either, so we are keying on for example `licensor` + `contractNumber`.

Is this normal in complex HLF applications? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your questions related to 1) managing unique keys and also states/statelists and 2) what are the assets, AND parameters to your transactions (to apply to the asset lifecycle or participant lifecycle as appropriate). Yes, it is normal to have varied keys as you describe.

Firstly, I would refer you to the logical and physical representations in the Multiple States commentary in the Process & Data Design section in Fabric docs -> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/developapps/architecture.html#logical-representation

Your key formation would be OK if others in your blockchain network consortium can similarly create records (and prevent collisions with others in your network), given the commonality of the keys/records other orgs/entities that will be committing to the ledger in that same blockchain network.

From your question, seems you have a Contract (asset) and Licensable widgets(asset).

Your contract asset (composite) key seems fine - its all about uniqueness for the most part and allowing for growth. That asset is created by (say) a createContract transaction.

Your widget asset key seems fine (eg. asset just created, no licensees yet), as presumably that key combo is unique in the network - this is created by the 'available' transaction. Initial licensed state is 'none'..etc.

Finally, the 'licensing' transaction can either update the existing widget  (with a licensee parameter in the trxn - 'licensee' is an attribute of 'widget' (or array if multiple licensees), tied back to the same licensor/widgetId key). The first licensee updates the state of the widget to 'licensed' (as opposed to 'none' etc etc)

As for the 'payment' transaction, not enough info: but you need to ask, what asset is being updated (does it exist yet - what's its asset key) And what are the parameters to the transaction, that will be applied to the asset (or different assets, if a unit of work updates 'multiples') - btw did you mean 'ContactNum/Licensee'? Anyway, food for thought.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful response. Very much appreciated.